# How do I recreate this design of silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I have a silverlight sample code that looks like this simple design of just an APP and a PAGE file.  I want to recreate this sort of setup from scratch to create a project that ouputs a silverlight program yet it only has these couple of files along with some support files. I went through the creation of a number of Silverlight creations and none produced such a simple and small design. How do I create such a formation that is just an App and a Page and such a few additional files from scratch and still have it output as a silverlight app?

[image: http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/small.jpg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to create this kind of project - I see you are using Visual Studio 2010, simply go to : file-new-project. On the left window there should be a tab for the templates. Select Silverlight (it will be under Visual C#). In the main window, select "Silverlight application". Once you named your project and click ok, you will be prompted on whether to host the page in a new website. Untick the checkbox and click ok. Now you will have your project exactly as it looks in your image.

Just note though, as you run it in VS, it will automatically generate a page for the app to run in, but since you indicated that it should not create a website to host it in, when wanting to deploy, you will have to create your own page and add the required markup yourself.